# Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, jackson

I have One-To-Many relationship, here is my code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "catalog")
public class Catalog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "catalog_id")
    private int catalog_id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 3, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mycatalogorder")
    private List<Order> orders;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mycatalog")
    private List<CatalogItem> items;

    // setters and getters
}

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "catalogitem")
 public class CatalogItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "catalogitem_id")
    private int catalogitem_id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 3, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private Double price;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="ordercatalogitem", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private OrderItem morderitem;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="catalog_id", nullable=false)
    private Catalog mycatalog;

    // setters and getters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private int order_id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 3, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 3, max = 1024)
    @Column(name = "note", nullable = false)
    private String note;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "ddmmYYYY HH:mm:ss")
    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false)
    private Date created;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="myorder")
    private Set<OrderItem> orderItems;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="catalog_id", nullable=false)
    private Catalog mycatalogorder;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        created = new Date();
    }

    // setters and getters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "orderitem")
public class OrderItem {

    @Id
    @Column(name="catalogitem_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="catalogitem"))
    private int catalogitem_id;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private CatalogItem ordercatalogitem;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id", nullable=false)
    private Order myorder;
     // setters and getters
}
```

And I am getting the exception:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of
>   role: com.example.helios.model.Catalog.items, could not initialize
>   proxy - no Session; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily
>   initialize a collection of role:
>   com.example.helios.model.Catalog.items, could not initialize proxy -
>   no Session
>     org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:271)
>     org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:222)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:183)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)

My versions is:

- SpringFramework 4.2.4.RELEASE
- Hibernate 4.3.11.Final
- Jackson 2.7.4
- Jacksontype 2.7.1

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is the normal Hibernate behaviour

In one to many relations, hibernate loads the father entity (Catalog in your case) but it will load the children entities List (List items and List orders in your case) in a LAZY mode

This means you can't access to these objects because they are just proxies and not real objects

This is usefull in order to avoid to load the full DB when you execute a query

You have 2 solution:

1. Load children entities in EAGER mode (I strongly suggest to you to not do it because you can load the full DB.... but it is something related to your scenario
2. You don't serialize in your JSON the children entities by using the com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore property

Angelo

Comment: but the second solution is static.. in a project we need sometimes the related entities and sometimes no. This EntityManager lifecycle with the automatic serialization done by spring  is a terrible pitfall.

Answer (score 3):

It's caused by an infinite loop when parsing datas to JSON.

You can solve this by using `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` annotations.

Definitions from API :

- JsonManagedReference (https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html) :

  > Annotation used to indicate that annotated property is part of two-way
  >   linkage between fields; and that its role is "parent" (or "forward")
  >   link. Value type (class) of property must have a single compatible
  >   property annotated with JsonBackReference. Linkage is handled such
  >   that the property annotated with this annotation is handled normally
  >   (serialized normally, no special handling for deserialization); it is
  >   the matching back reference that requires special handling
- JsonBackReference: (https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html):

  > Annotation used to indicate that associated property is part of
  >   two-way linkage between fields; and that its role is "child" (or
  >   "back") link. Value type of the property must be a bean: it can not be
  >   a Collection, Map, Array or enumeration. Linkage is handled such that
  >   the property annotated with this annotation is not serialized; and
  >   during deserialization, its value is set to instance that has the
  >   "managed" (forward) link.

Example:

**Owner.java:**

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
Set<Car> cars;
```

**Car.java:**

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
private Owner owner;
```

Another solution is to use `@JsonIgnore` which will just set null to the field.

Answer (score 2):

A third option which can be useful if you don't want to use EAGER mode and load up everything is to use Hibernate::initialize and only load what you need.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Catalog catalog = (Catalog) session.load(Catalog.class, catalogId);
Hibernate.initialize(shelf);
```

[More information](http://learningviacode.blogspot.be/2012/11/forcefully-initializing-proxies-in.html?_sm_au_=iHVJVsMjr7q61qjJ)

Comment: Yes... you are right... I forgot it; but you must always be in hibernate session

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Indeed it's not the most practical one. To be used when EAGER has too much performance impact.

Comment: i totally agree with you :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but a fixed by:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "assigned_ingredient", referencedColumnName = "ingredient_id")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) // Changing the fetch profile you can solve the problem
@Where(clause = "active_ind = 'Y'")
@OrderBy(clause = "meal_id ASC")
private List<Well> ingredients;
```

you can have more information here: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for this task with Hibernate. I marked hibernate releation with @JsonIgnore and use custom field for jackson, in which I check if the field is loaded. If you need serialize collection to json then you should manualy call collection getter during hibernate transaciton.

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "myorder")
private List<OrderItem> orderItems = new ArrayList<>();

@JsonProperty(value = "order_items", access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
private List<OrderItem> getOrderItemsList() {

    if(Hibernate.isInitialized(this.relatedDictionary)){
        return this.relatedDictionary;
    } else{
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

@JsonProperty(value = "order_items", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private void setOrderItemsList(List<OrderItem> orderItems) {
    this.orderItems = orderItems;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but this might still help someone facing a similar issue. To solve the problem, iterate through the list of items and set the lazy-loadable collection to null. Then set your mapper to include NON-NULL

```
 for (Catalog c : allCatalogs) {
        c.setItems(null);
    }

objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using FetchType.LAZY , if still getting the error "Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role" , that may be probably caused by somewhere in the logic (perhaps in a controller) , Catalog is being tried to be deserialized that contains list of catalog items which is a proxy but the transaction has already ended to get that. 
So create a new model ('CatalogResource' similar to catalog but without the list of items).
Then create a catalogResource object out of the Catalog (which is returned from the query)

```html
public class CatalogResource {
    private int catalog_id;
    private String name;
    private List<Order> orders;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to your problem (which also is the simplest) is to set your FetchType to LAZY and simply annotate the oneToMany collection fields using @transient.
Setting FetchType to EAGER isn't a good idea most times.
Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

"You don't serialize in your JSON the children entities by using the `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` property"

Add `@JsonIgnore` for hibernate lazy loading properties eg. `@ManyToOne`. That should work