# Spring failed to lazily initialize a collection - rest api

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

i have got an error when I try to get response from my rest api. The error says..

```
"message": "Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: pl.bmstefanski.some_package.entity.impl.GuildEntityImpl.regions, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: pl.bmstefanski.some_package.entity.impl.GuildEntityImpl.regions, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->pl.bmstefanski.some_package.entity.impl.GuildEntityImpl[\"regions\"])"
```

Pointed collection:

```
  @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
  @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = false)
  private List<String> regions;
```

Have you got any idea, why jackson cannot map this collection to json format?

Comment: the error is related to the fact that you have proxies object and you are outside of hibernate session so it's impossibile to marshalling/unmarshalling them You may give a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089966/could-not-write-content-failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I just need to add custom converter list -> string, like so:
@Converter

```
public class StringListConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> list) {
    return String.join(",", list);  
  }

  @Override
  public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String joined) {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(joined.split(",")));
  }

}
```

and then annotate my field with,

```
  @Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
  @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = false)
  private List<String> regions;
```

source: [Convert list in entity to single string column in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048978/convert-list-in-entity-to-single-string-column-in-database)

Answer (score 0):

Try it : It might solve this issue, if not, you follow below link, that have more solutions

@ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)

@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = false)

@JsonIgnore

private List regions;

[How to persist a property of type List<String> in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287201/how-to-persist-a-property-of-type-liststring-in-jpa)

Comment: I can't ignore it, this is primary feature of my api.

Comment: Have you used @Transactional annotation

Comment: I think this is not the problem's cause. But in answer to your question, I am using a spring data repositories, so I didn't have to add, a `@Transactional` annotation.